# How can I vertically align labels in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple login page with name and password fields and I want to vertically align the input and the label.

Here is my code:

Html

```
<label>Nombre: </label>
<input class="name" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"><br>
<label>Password:</label>
<input class="pass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
```

Css

```
.pass {
    font-family: apple;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.name {
    font-family: apple;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

How I can do it?

Comment: What kind of vertical alignment do you need? Center?

Comment: I want: Nombre at the left and password at the same vertical align at the left and the input at the left starting at the same vertical place

Comment: I can't explain it better how I can show you an image?

Comment: you could attach an image to your post.

Comment: You want the label and field to be in the same spot?

Answer (score 1):

```
label {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 5em;
 padding-right: 1em;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/wivugisu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="somelabel">
        <label >Nombre: </label>
    </span>
    <input class="name" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
</div>
<div>
    <span class="somelabel">
        <label class="somelabel">Password:</label>
    </span>
    <input class="pass" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.pass {
    font-family: apple;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.name {
    font-family: apple;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.somelabel {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure it is what you need with your new explanation;
I've just put them in line, no CSS was needed in that case.
Let me update it, 1 second.